# How can I see my choice of day in calender from the toolbox?

Tags: c#

I have a Textbox and a Calender:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="datepicker" runat="server" CssClass="input-date date-icn small-label" AutoCompleteType="BusinessZipCode" /asp:TextBox>

<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged"       
/asp:Calendar>
```

when i pick the date from my calender i want it to show on the textbox, how can i do it?

this is my code behind:

```
protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Calendar Calendar = new Calendar();
    Panel PanelCalendar = new Panel();
    PanelCalendar.Controls.Add(Calendar);
}
```

please help me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`Calendar.SelectedDate` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.selecteddate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead?

> Gets or sets the selected date.

Like;

```
datepicker.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString();
```

Comment: ok it helps! thank you...and do you know what can i do so the page will not refresh itself?

Comment: The entire page or part of the page has to refresh in order to update the page content. Use Ajax for partial page refreshes or the entire page will refresh.

Comment: another question... :) sorry, I'm a beginner in c#... I wanted to know how can i click on the text box and the calender will show? i don't want the calender to show when i load the page, only when i click on the textbox ???